# Project Euler prob. 4 the Largest palindrome product

Tags: java

https://projecteuler.net/problem=4

A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

Here is my code and I find the answer as 580085 but it is not the correct answer:

```
    public class asdas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a=100,b=100,answer=0;
        while(a<=999)
        {
            b=100;
            while(b<=999)
            {
                int product=a*b;
                int reverse=0;

                while(product>0)
                {
                    int lastDigit=product%10;
                    reverse=(reverse*10)+lastDigit;
                    product=product/10;
                }
                product=a*b;
                if(product==reverse)
                {
                    answer=product;
                }
                b++;
            }
            a++;
        }
        System.out.println(answer); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if(product==reverse)
{
    answer=product;
}
```

You're assuming that if you find a palindrome, it's the largest. That's not true though.

For example, 101*100 is calculated after 100*102, even though the latter is larger. In fact, right after calculating 998*999 (997,002), you calculate 999*100 (99,900), which is nearly 10 times smaller!

You should add another check to make sure the new product is greater:

```
if(product==reverse && product>answer) {
    answer = product;
}
```